# php cookie или СУБД

Tags: php, cookie

Доброго времени.

Задался таким вопросом (точнее двумя).

1. Есть данные пользователя которые я записываю в куку имя,йд-юзера,роль,хеш ...
   и криптую всё это, кука выходит 187-байт , вопрос что целесообразно использовать ?
   доставать данные с БД через йд-юзера или извлекать данные из куки
2. Что лучше использовать одну большую куку или разбить её на несколько мелких ?

Спасибо всем за участие

Answer (score 1):

1. Есть ли иная идентификация юзера, кроме, как по куки – напр. может ли он восстановить пароль на свой email? Если для вас нормальна потеря всех данных юзера с потерей его кук (зашёл с другого компа на работе)  – лучше куки: вам меньше данных хранить.
2. Одна кука, включая название, данные Expire и сами данные – может весить до 4kB. Отсюда я бы исходил, планируя разбиение на несколько кук.

Comment: Не понял вас, почему данные могут потеряться ? они же в Куке + есть сессия , конечно может восстановить почту, набрал имя,пароль, почту сравнил хеш юзера и выслал пароль .

Comment: Сбросил куки – всё, больше нигде его имя, роль не хранятся?

Comment: дык ,сбросил куки и всё = юзер не зарегистрирован , в чём проблема ?

Answer (score 0):

Доставать данные с БД через йд-юзера.

На любой подобный вопрос ответ дать легко.
Вариант используется повсеместно? Используй его. 
Завиральная идея, высосанная из пальца без малейшей причины? Оставь его для художественной фантастики.
Есть какие-то страхи, из-за которых хочется сделать не по-человечески? **Вот их и надо изложить в своем вопросе.**